# Discordjs bot embed gifs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My bot are sends random gifs but not embed. I wanna sends random gifs with embed. How can I this ?

Codes:

```
  if (msg.author.bot) return;
  if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'xgif' ) {
      number = 100;
      imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number -1 + 1)) + 1;
      client.channels.cache.get(`channelID`).send( {files: ["./images/" + imageNumber + ".gif"]})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first do

```
  const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js')
```

That'll get RichEmbed for you. Then, do

```
const embed = new RichEmbed()
```

There's a lot of things you can do to change the embed. There's

1. `.setColor(hexidecimal)`
2. `.setThumbnail(normally user.displayAvatarURL)`
3. `.setFooter(whatever you want)`
4. `.setTimestamp()`
5. `.setDescription(whatever you want)`
6. `.setAuthor(whatever you want)`
7. `.addField(stuff)`